# What is the correct way to setup Azure Artifacts in Azure DevOps?

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am using azure devops and I want to create a setup so that I can build java jar files in an azure pipeline and then publish them to an artifactory in azure. I want those files to be available in my maven pom files so that I can download them locally and build my project with them as well as be availble when azure pipelines are running. I saw the artifacts section in azue devops, but when I read more about it, it sounds like this is for a different use case. Is it possible to do what I want in azure? If so what is the correct way? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to do what I want in azure? If so what is the correct way?

Not an expert on this by any means, but I have some experience working with CI pipelines.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops) it is explained how to create a private `azure mvn repo`. This will allow you to pull/push `.jar` files to/from your local machine. If this can be done on your local machine for sure it can be done from a CI server in the same way.

So you can just configure a CI server by an init script in the same way you would configure your local machine based on the contents of the article above.

There might also be a better way, probably Azure has some sort of a reusable action/pipeline step, which does the build/deploy process for you, so that you don't need to write and maintain your own `init` script.